# Flashing radio to European G1 via Amon_Ra process: which version of radio 2.22.19.26i is safe for DangerSPL?

Tags: cyanogenmod, htc-dream, radio-firmware

[Cyanogenmod's wiki](http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=HTC_Dream%3a_Rooting&oldid=14594#Amon_Ra.27s_Recovery_process) says to use **dream_magic.radio-2.22.19.26i-signed.zip**

But this [revision](http://oldwiki.cyanogenmod.org/index.php?title=HTC_Dream%3a_DangerSPL&oldid=14581#Prerequisites) says to use **ota-radio-2_22_19_26I.zip**

These files differ. **My question is: which of them (or both?) is safe to use before flashing DangerSPL for the first time?**

NB. The main difference between them seems to be that their `META-INF/com/google/android/update-script` files differ thus:

- dream_magic.radio-2.22.19.26i-signed.zip:

  ```
  assert getprop("ro.product.device") == "dream" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "dream" || getprop("ro.product.device") == "sapphire" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "sapphire"
  ```
- ota-radio-2_22_19_26I.zip:

  ```
  assert getprop("ro.product.device") == "dream" || getprop("ro.build.product") == "dream"
  ```

Comment: Any radio v2 or greater *should* be safe, but no reason not to flash the latest - that is known to be safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are the same radio. the file name is just different. notice the version number in both is: 2.22.19.26i. The first update-script was modified a bit so it supports both the dream (adp1/g1), and the magic (adp2). The OTA radio looks like it was specifically for the dream.

I, myself, would use the one that is for both the dream & magic, but really, it shouldn't matter.

Comment: The Dream & Magic/Sapphire are basically the same hardware as far as the radio is concerned.